# C pointer to 2d array in a struct

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I have a structure with a 2d array.  I'm passing a pointer to this structure to a function, where I need to edit the 2d array.  I am struggling to find the correct syntax to reference the 2d array from within my function.

```
#define TG_WIDTH 10
#define TG_HEIGHT 20

typedef enum {
   BLOCK_T = 0,
   BLOCK_LINE,
   BLOCK_SQUARE,
   BLOCK_L,
   BLOCK_L_REVERSE,
   BLOCK_S,
   BLOCK_S_REVERSE
} block_t;

typedef struct {
   char y_max[TG_WIDTH];
   block_t grid[TG_WIDTH][TG_HEIGHT];
} scratchpad_t;

bool
placeBlock(scratchpad_t *sp) {
   block_t (*g)[TG_WIDTH] = sp->grid;

   g[1][2] = BLOCK_T;
}
```

This gives me an "initialization from incompatible pointer type" warning though.  What is the correct way to define/initialize "g" here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `TG_WIDTH` to `TG_HEIGHT`:

```
block_t (*g)[TG_HEIGHT] = sp->grid;
```

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with the simplest possible?

```
sp->grid[1][2] = BLOCK_T;
```

If you have many array accesses in your function and you want to factor out `sp->grid` because you think this will be faster (fewer dereferences), I think that all optimizing C compilers take care of that pretty well.

Comment: I'm porting a perl script to C and in the perl script I had used the g[1][2] syntax everywhere so that is what led me in this direction.  Your solution works though...I should have thought of that :)

Comment: I'm still curious as to what the syntax should be for the way I was trying to do it originally

Comment: You already had it, just switched the dimensions... :-)  It is `block_t (*g)[TG_HEIGHT] = sp->grid;` (a pointer, i.e. an array, of arrays of blocks, each of which having `TG_HEIGHT` elements).  Somebody answered it but deleted his answer.